# Gmail API Error 400 - Precondition check failed happens inconsistently

Tags: gmail-api

I'm struggling with a Gmail API issue. A few things to get started:

- Using OAuth2
- My account is GSuite enabled
- Scope includes Modify
- My program is in GoLang

My program is sending an email on behalf of an authed user. Nearly all Gmail API functionality works perfectly - I'm able to create a draft, send an email without creating a draft, operate on labels, etc.

The issue seems to occur only when I attempt to send a draft object using the `users.drafts.send` method: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/send

When I create a draft message and then fire off the request to send the message, I inconsistently get back error 400 `Precondition check failed.`

This is a POST request to the endpoint https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/send?uploadType=multipart

The weird part leaving me completely baffled is that I can make an identical request directed at a different draft message ID using the same OAuth access token half a second later and it works perfectly.

This request failed - timestamp 2022-01-04T19:43:50.278Z

`Method:POST URL:https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/send?uploadType=multipart Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Authorization:[Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM9mREDACTED] Content-Type:[application/json]] Body:{Reader:0xc0004e7dd0} GetBody:0x7198e0 ContentLength:70 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:gmail.googleapis.com Form:map[] PostForm:map[] MultipartForm:<nil> Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr: RequestURI: TLS:<nil> Cancel:<nil> Response:<nil> ctx:0xc000044060`

Body object:
`{"id":"r155747228619414494","message":{"threadId":"17e269e7bb12bece"}}`

And this request succeeded - timestamp 2022-01-04T19:43:50.230Z

`Method:POST URL:https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/send?uploadType=multipart Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Authorization:[Bearer ya29.a0ARrdaM9mREDACTED] Content-Type:[application/json]] Body:{Reader:0xc00061b920} GetBody:0x7198e0 ContentLength:70 TransferEncoding:[] Close:false Host:gmail.googleapis.com Form:map[] PostForm:map[] MultipartForm:<nil> Trailer:map[] RemoteAddr: RequestURI: TLS:<nil> Cancel:<nil> Response:<nil> ctx:0xc000044060`

Body object:
`{"id":"r107084306592061046","message":{"threadId":"17e269e82b321030"}}`

I am capturing errors for scenarios like rate-limiting - the error in question is very specifically `Precondition check failed.`, and I have only seen it so far using this specific endpoint.

Everything I've found online suggests this error points to an issue with auth. I have authed, un-authed, and re-authed, all with no difference.

I've also gone back into the developer page above and used the Gmail test tool to send the same request body values, and the draft sends successfully, which suggests this *probably* isn't a corrupted draft message.

All that context to ask 2 questions:

1. Has anyone seen a Gmail error where that error message indicates something I may not be considering? The Gmail documentation has nothing I can see about that error message.
2. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening inconsistently with requests that are essentially identical?

Thanks!

Comment: It's been a few days and I haven't heard anything yet, which makes sense, because this is pretty weird and niche. For anyone coming to look, I am currently treating these messages the same as I do rate limiting, and it's at least a sufficient bandage. If anyone from the Gmail team happens to see this, I would love a bit more information in the docs about what this error message means.

Comment: I can double down on the issue - in our case it is `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages` endpoint. We have a public Oauth Gmail app and 400 "FailedPrecondition" error happens from time to time (maybe once in 10k requests). Despite it signalling bad request it's temporary, so I placed a retry in that case.

Would be awesome to have a response from Gmail team on that

Answer (score 0):

We recently started getting `400` "Precondition check failed." inconsistently from

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile
```

and it seems to coincide with days when we make more requests than usual, so my current theory is that it is some kind of rate-limit.  However, it could also be a rare internal error on Google's end (which would also be more likely to occur if we query them more).
Based on the comments, it seems like this can occur on several different endpoints like:

```
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile
GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages
POST https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts/send
```

If this is a rate-limit, you might want to know how many requests we can send. Our "normal" amount of queries is about 1000 API requests per hour, and the 3 days when we got this error we spiked to 3000+ API requests per hour.

It looks like the official rate-limits are here
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota
and if I'm reading that correctly we have a quota of 250 "getProfile" requests per user per second, which I doubt we are hitting. Perhaps we are somehow hitting the daily limit which is no longer specified?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76965320/1877508

Comment: Have been getting the same error on `GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/history` endpoint as well. Happens inconsistently. And using the same params to call the endpoint few hours later works fine. What gives?