# Gmail API usage limits - how many emails can I receive using the API?

Tags: gmail

Can someone please help me understand the information on this page? It says that I can use 250 quota units per second and that receiving one email "costs" 5 quota units. Does that mean that I can receive 50 emails per second? Or per day? Because at the top of the page it mentions:

> "The Gmail API is subject to a daily usage limit"

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

Also, in their documentation on "Apps Scripts" they mention a limit of 50k emails read/written per day:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the past](http://web.archive.org/web/20220318081812/https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota), that page had an extra row that says the daily limit is one billion per day. Removing that line implies Gmail now has a dynamic daily limit (i.e., some users may get a higher/lower limit depending on their access pattern), but that per-second limit stays. So you can still get 50 emails per second, but excessive use along with other APIs might get you limited before the day ended.

Comment: Thanks @Martheen! Do you happen to know, would excessive use be measured across my organization, or just for one user? I'm looking to download approximately  3 thousand emails a day and wondering if I'll run into any problems.

Comment: if you have a limit of 50 per second so you can at least download 86400 per day